# what make a function execute before another one?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a html page My goal is  when i click on the button The  first function execute and after that the second one execute

but the actual result is that the function 2 execute first i tried to write an if condition that if the function 1 execute then execute function 2 but it does not work !

How can i make the function 1 execute first and  what make a function execute before another one ?

```
but.addEventListener('click',function(){

function FirstFunction(){


   var Interval= setInterval(function(){

    // Code

    },500); 

};

FirstFunction(); 


function SecondFunction(){

    // code

};

 if( FirstFunction() ){

       SecondFunction();

};          

});
```

Comment: `setInterval` starts a timer, it does not block. functions are also hoisted to the top of their scope

Answer (score 0):

```js
but.addEventListener('click',function(){

function FirstFunction(secFunction){


   var Interval= setInterval(function(){

    // Code
    
    secFunction();

    },500); 

};

function SecondFunction(){

    // code

};
FirstFunction(SecondFunction); 
});
```